# Where to put external config files in a Kotlin Gradle project?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I use a standard Maven/Gradle project structure putting source code under `src/main/kotlin` and automatically collected resources under `src/main/resources`:

```
\myapp
 -\src
    -\main
      -\kotlin
        -\com
          -\projectname
            -\MyApp.kt
       -\resources
         - som_file.txt
```

This works fine to package my distribution with the `distZip` task and all resources end up in a `jar` which is then zipped into the following structure:

```
myapp
-\bin\
-\libs\
```

I am not sure where to put external config files in my Kotlin project (e.g. `db.config`) which the user could edit later. Is there a correct location for external config files in Gradle project?

Comment: There is none. You can put them anywhere outside of those "standard" source code and resource locations and write a small Gradle task to copy them into the structure that is being zipped. Check `distZip` to see where it puts all the files before zipping to hook in your own logic.

Comment: Just to clarify the observable behavior: main resources are collected from `src/main/resources` by  the Gradle `ProcessResources` task (https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html) before the `jar` task is executed zipping the compiled classes and collected resources. As you do not want those configs in the jar, you cannot put them into a resource folder (default or custom) and need a custom solution that is run after the `jar` task but before, or as a part of `distZip`.